# C# Unable to cast error calling method with a dynamic argument

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic, casting

I am having an intermittent exception from my code.  I have a method with a dynamic parameter.  My code is essentially looping through a lot of types and registering mappings.  The dynamic parameter represents an expression mapping the type to a specific property of the type.

Every few runs one call (could be any call to this method, there is no pattern) to AddIndexAttributes will fail with an 'Unable to cast' exception trying to cast the type of the dynamic expression to another expression type completely unreferenced by this code.  Presumably, this is a type which has previously been mapped using this method during this run.

```
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`2[Type1,System.Byte[]]]' to type 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`2[Type2,System.Nullable`1[System.DateTimeOffset]]]'.
    at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Type , PropertyInfo , Object , StructuralTypeConfiguration`1 , Dictionary`2 , Dictionary`2 )
    at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecuteVoid6[T0,T1,T2,T3,T4,T5](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3, T4 arg4, T5 arg5)
    at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Type , PropertyInfo , Object , StructuralTypeConfiguration`1 , Dictionary`2 , Dictionary`2 )
    at TypeConfigurationHelper.Configure[T](StructuralTypeConfiguration`1 type) in C:\\project\TypeConfigurationHelper.cs:line 127
```

Where Type1 is T (see code below) and Type2 is another type in my database which is not being used or referenced anywhere in this call.  Byte[] is the type of the current parameter in the loop, DateTimeOffset is, I presume, the type of a property of Type2.

The exception itself is coming from System.Core and I have been able to trace the error using VS's framework debugging.  I can see it get as far as UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecuteVoid6 and it runs its first rule and crashes.

This code is called for all types in my EF database in one thread, one after the other in a loop.

Simplified Code:

```
  public static void Configure<T>(StructuralTypeConfiguration<T> type) where T : class
  {
     var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties();

     //These dictionaries keep track of whether our composite indexes are valid or not.
     var compositeIndexMaximumOrder = new Dictionary<string, int>();
     var compositeIndexCounts = new Dictionary<string, int>();

     foreach (var property in properties)
     {

        //Get the property for the item on the type
        PropertyInfo pi = typeof(T).GetProperty(property.Name);

        //Get an expression for the type => property
        //To support inherited objects we use ReflectedType instead of DeclaringType
        dynamic expression = pi.ReflectedType.TypeMapExpression(pi.Name);

        //Place to configure anything that is not tied to a field definition.
        AddIndexAttributes<T>(pi, expression, type, compositeIndexMaximumOrder, compositeIndexCounts);
     }

  }

  private static void AddIndexAttributes<T>(PropertyInfo property, dynamic expression, StructuralTypeConfiguration<T> type, Dictionary<string, int> compositeIndexMaximumOrder,
     Dictionary<string, int> compositeIndexCounts) where T : class
  {
     List<IndexAttribute> indexAttributes = convertSymIndexAttributesToDotNetIndexAttributes(property, compositeIndexMaximumOrder, compositeIndexCounts);
     if (indexAttributes.Count() > 0)
     {
        type.Property(expression).HasColumnAnnotation("Index", new IndexAnnotation(indexAttributes));
     }
  }
```

Why is this crashing? Why would it be trying to cast a dynamic value to a completely unreferenced type?  I've tried to read up about what CallSite etc is actually doing, but I can't see why it would be trying to make a cast at that point.

My project is using .Net 4.5.

TypeMapExpression:

```
  public static dynamic TypeMapExpression(this Type type, string parameterName)
  {
     //Get a parameter expression for the type
     var parameter = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Parameter(type);
     //Get a lambda expression for the type
     return System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Lambda(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Property(parameter, parameterName), parameter);
  }
```

Comment: What is `TypeMapExpression(...)` method, can we see it?

Comment: Updated question to include source for TypeMapExpression.

Comment: Thank you. But sorry, can't duplicate.

Comment: I'm not surprised, it happens so infrequently.  I'm currently trying newer versions of the .net framework to see if it resolves this.  I was just hoping someone had encountered this before and could point me in the right direction.  The more I look into it the more it seems like a framework bug, but if it is that surely someone would have encountered it before.